# How do I set a /kill command on a block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

You can set a `/kill` command on a command block, I know that, but how do I do it? I am making a map, so please help!

Comment: kill (name, @e, @a, @p). Just google this...

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty lacking in detail, so I'll give you an overview.

First off, you need a command block (Directly from the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block)):

> Command blocks can be obtained by using the pick block control or with various commands, such as `/give <player> minecraft:command_block <amount>`.
>
> Command blocks are not available in the creative inventory, cannot be broken in survival mode or if you do not have operator permissions (1.9[upcoming]), are not flammable, and have the same blast resistance as bedrock. Command blocks cannot be moved by a piston.

Then enter your desired [kill command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#kill) into the command block, e.g.

- `/kill Name` where "Name" is a players name, will kill that player
- `/kill @e` To kill everything
- `/kill @e[type=Sheep]` To kill all sheep
- `/kill @e[type=!Player]` Will kill anything which isn't a player (Including de-spawning dropped items)

You then activate the command block in a normal way, the easiest of which is either directly from a switch/lever, or a redstone current.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly `/kill` a block (at least I don't think), as blocks are notentities. However there are some exceptions including Item Frames and Minecarts. What you can do as an alternative is `/setblock x y z air` for example, to set a block to air (basically removing it completely).

With Item Frames, you can do `/kill @e[type=ItemFrame]`. Same with minecarts (just making the `ItemFrame` into a `MinecartRidable`

Comment: Blocks are not entities while item frames/minecarts are entities. As well, /kill does **not** support NBT data. It's only: `/kill <target>`

Comment: @Skylinerw my mistake. I do know that blocks are not entities, I just forgot to add don't :D. Can be interpretable since I said you cannot kill a block

Comment: He's not asking to kill a block. He asked how to put a `kill` command on a command block.

Comment: @mbomb007 Well then that's just a right click

Comment: @JohnSmith Yeah, I think he was asking for the syntax, but all he would've had to do is do some searching on the MC wiki. Idk.